# AuthController doesnot exist

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, composer-php, laragon

i am working on laravel 5.3.29 while making a controller i am getting error.

[image: Error While Running Project]

i search everywhere and already try this methods.

- composer update
- composer dump-autoload

My Routes file is.
[image]

My AuthController File.
[image]

Kindly if anyone knows where i am doing wrong let me know thankyou.

```
Laravel.log:
```

`[2017-01-15 07:30:32] local.ERROR: ReflectionException: Class     App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController does not exist in  C:\laragon\www\MainProject\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Con tainer.php:749
   Stack trace:
   #0   C:\laragon\www\MainProject\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(749): ReflectionClass->__construct('App\\Http\\Contro...')
   #1   C:\laragon\www\MainProject\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(644): Illuminate\Container\Container->build('App\\Http\\Contro...',  Array)
   #2 C:\laragon\www\MainProject\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php(709): Illuminate\Container\Container->make('App\\Http\\Contro...', Array)
   #3 C:\laragon\www\MainProject\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Route.php(203): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->make('App\\Http\\Contro...')
   #4 C:\laragon\www\MainProject\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Route.php(316): Illuminate\Routing\Route->getController()
   #5 C:\laragon\www\MainProject\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Route.php(278): Illuminate\Routing\Route->controllerMiddleware()
   #6 C:\laragon\www\MainProject\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php(666): Illuminate\Routing\Route->gatherMiddleware()
   #7 C:\laragon\www\MainProject\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php(646): Illuminate\Routing\Router->gatherRouteMiddleware(Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route))
   #8 C:\laragon\www\MainProject\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php(629): Illuminate\Routing\Router->runRouteWithinStack(Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
   #9 C:\laragon\www\MainProject\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php(607): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatchToRoute(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
   #10 C:\laragon\www\MainProject\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel.php(268): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
   #11 C:\laragon\www\MainProject\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
   #12 C:\laragon\www\MainProject\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode.php(46): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
   #13 C:\laragon\www\MainProject\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(137): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
   #14 C:\laragon\www\MainProject\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline.php(33): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
   #15 C:\laragon\www\MainProject\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(104): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
   #16 C:\laragon\www\MainProject\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel.php(150): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
   #17 C:\laragon\www\MainProject\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel.php(117): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
   #18 C:\laragon\www\MainProject\public\index.php(53): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
   #19 {main}

[2017-01-15 07:30:32] local.ERROR: ReflectionException: Class App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController does not exist in C:\laragon\www\MainProject\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php:749
Stack trace:
   #0 C:\laragon\www\MainProject\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(749): ReflectionClass->__construct('App\\Http\\Contro...')
    #1 C:\laragon\www\MainProject\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(644): Illuminate\Container\Container->build('App\\Http\\Contro...', Array)
   #2 C:\laragon\www\MainProject\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php(709): Illuminate\Container\Container->make('App\\Http\\Contro...', Array)
   #3 C:\laragon\www\MainProject\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Route.php(203): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->make('App\\Http\\Contro...')
   #4 C:\laragon\www\MainProject\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Route.php(316): Illuminate\Routing\Route->getController()
   #5 C:\laragon\www\MainProject\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Route.php(278): Illuminate\Routing\Route->controllerMiddleware()
   #6 C:\laragon\www\MainProject\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php(666): Illuminate\Routing\Route->gatherMiddleware()
   #7 C:\laragon\www\MainProject\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel.php(193): Illuminate\Routing\Router->gatherRouteMiddleware(Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route))
   #8 C:\laragon\www\MainProject\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel.php(163): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->gatherRouteMiddleware(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
   #9 C:\laragon\www\MainProject\public\index.php(58): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->terminate(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Illuminate\Http\Response))
   #10 {main}`

Comment: Please post code as code not as image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem that occurs because of manual entry file in Controller.

- i remove the manual file that i created with new file option in
  sublime
- And add again with laragon terminal php artisan make:controller
  AuthController.
- And copy pasted the previos code now its working smoothly.

Answer (score 6):

Due to namespace path not identified.

```
Route::group([

'middleware' => 'api',
'namespace' => 'App\Http\Controllers',
'prefix' => 'auth'

], function ($router) {

Route::post('login', 'AuthController@login');
Route::post('logout', 'AuthController@logout');
Route::post('refresh', 'AuthController@refresh');
Route::post('me', 'AuthController@me');

});
```

Answer (score 5):

There is a Auth folder name is missing in web.php
so it will be

> Auth\AuthController@getLogin

I was facing issue in laravel 8 while using above syntax so kindly use something like in web.php or api.php -

> use App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController

```
Route::post('login', [AuthController::class, 'getLogin']);
```

Answer (score 3):

Change the route to:

```
Route::get('/login', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogin');
```

Also make sure class file is in this directory:

```
app\Http\Controllers\Auth
```

Comment: i try this too but nothing happend

Comment: @Uzair what does `nothing happened` mean? Did you get empty screen? Did you get an error? What is the last error in `storage/logs/laravel.log`?

Comment: i mean the same errors that occurs Authcontroller doesnot exist. i am attaching laravel.log please check.

Answer (score 1):

in Laravel 4.2 , I don't think you need

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller
```

just remove it, and please be careful with your controller path

make sure your `AuthController.php` located in `app/controllers`

are you sure you are using Laravel 4.2 ? why are the routes in `web.php` ?

as long as I know, you are using Laravel 5.3 if you use that structure, please make sure again which Laravel version you are using

Comment: Yes Dzaky Sorry you are right i am using 5.3 version i just check and i remove those two namespace and use lines but nothing changes the result.

Comment: try to change 

`namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;` to

`namespace App\Http\Controllers;`

and make sure your `AuthController.php` is in 

`app\Http\Controllers`

Comment: and make sure your route is `Route::get('/login', 'AuthController@getLogin');` , tell me what you get

Comment: i remove manual entry file in controller that i made with name AuthController and add file by php artisan make:controller AuthController now its working smoothly thank you for help :)

Answer (score 1):

To resolve AuthController doesn't exist error in Laravel 8 or higher version, just go to

app-> Providers -> RouteServiceProvider.php and un-comment below line.

```
protected $namespace = 'App\\Http\\Controllers';
```

Reference
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SYicSVNMeqc

Answer (score 0):

Change namespace to `App\Http\Controllers` instead of `App\Http\Controllers\Auth`

Or alternatively, in your routes.php say `Route::get('/login', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogin');`

Answer (score 0):

Route::group([

```
'middleware' => 'api',
'namespace' => 'App\Http\Controllers',
'prefix' => 'auth'
```

], function ($router) {

```
Route::post('login', 'AuthController@login');
Route::post('logout', 'AuthController@logout');
Route::post('refresh', 'AuthController@refresh');
Route::post('profile', 'AuthController@profile');
```

});

I removed this 'namespace' => 'App\Http\Controllers' to

Route::group([

```
'middleware' => 'api',
'prefix' => 'auth'
```

], function ($router) {

```
Route::post('login', 'AuthController@login');
Route::post('logout', 'AuthController@logout');
Route::post('refresh', 'AuthController@refresh');
Route::post('profile', 'AuthController@profile');
```

});

and add this line to the top

use App\Http\Controllers\AuthController;